Identify a familiar fundamental group from attaching $2$-cells to $\mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1$
Question: Let $X = \mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1$ be the wedge sum of three circles. We shall give the circles the labels $a$, $b$, and $c$ with orientations in the counterclockwise direction. We attach three $2$-cells via the maps

$\phi_1(s) = a\cdot b \cdot a^{-1} \cdot b^{-1} \cdot c^3 (s)$
$\phi_2(s) = a(s)$
$\phi_3(s) = a^{-1}(s)$

Let $A \subset X$ be the subcomplex given by the shared point and the circle labeled with $c$. Show the adjunction $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of familiar spaces.
Attempt: We begin by recalling the following results.
Cell Attachement: Let $\phi : \partial \mathbb D ^ 2 \to B \subset X$, then $\pi_1(X \cup_{\phi} \mathbb D ^ 2) \cong \pi_1(X)/\langle\langle[\phi]\rangle\rangle$.
Munkres Theorem 68.7: Let $G = G_1 * G_2$. Let $N_i$ be a normal subgroup of $G_i$ for $i=1,2$. If $N$ is the least normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $N_1$ and $N_2$, then
$$G / N \cong (G_1 / N_1) * (G_2 / N_2)$$
We start to identify common patterns in attaching functions.

$\phi_1(s) = \underbrace{a\cdot b \cdot a^{-1} \cdot b^{-1}}_{\text{Torus}} \cdot \underbrace{c^3}_{\text{3-fold dunce cap}} (s)$
$\phi_2(s) = a(s)$
$\phi_3(s) = a^{-1}(s)$

Essentially, the quotient identifies $c$ with shared point, so we end up forgetting about the $c^3$ term in $\phi_1$. I also believe that $\langle \langle [\alpha^{-1}] \rangle \rangle = \langle \langle [\alpha]^{-1} \rangle \rangle =  \langle \langle [\alpha] \rangle \rangle$. (This could be wildly mistaken wishful thinking on my part.)
I argue that the space is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb T ^ 2 \vee \mathbb S ^ 2$ where $\mathbb T ^ 2$ is the torus and $\mathbb S ^ 2$ is the 2-sphere.
The only other possible answer I can think of is $\mathbb T ^ 2 \vee \mathbb {RP}^2$; however, I do not believe that the attaching maps for $a$ and $a^{-1}$ coincide with $\mathbb{RP}^2$.
Here is an attempt to make my argument rigorous
$$\pi_1(X \cup_{\phi_1} \mathbb D ^ 2  \cup_{\phi_2} \mathbb D ^ 2  \cup_{\phi_3} \mathbb D ^ 2) \cong \langle a, b, c : gaba^{-1}b^{-1}c^3g^{-1}, gag^{-1} \text{ where $g$ is any free group product of $a$, $b$, and $c$.}\rangle$$
I do not know how to justify forgetting $c$ rigorously, but I argue that the group becomes.
$$\pi_1(X \cup_{\phi_1} \mathbb D ^ 2  \cup_{\phi_2} \mathbb D ^ 2  \cup_{\phi_3} \mathbb D ^ 2) \cong \langle a, b : gaba^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1}, gag^{-1} \text{ where $g$ is any free group product of $a$ and $b$.}\rangle$$
If $\pi_1(\mathbb T ^ 2) = \langle a, b : gaba^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1}\rangle$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb S ^ 2) = \langle a : gag^{-1} \rangle$, then Seifart van Kampen (with a contractible intersection) and theorem 68.7, we have that $\pi_1(\mathbb T ^ 2 \vee \mathbb S ^ 2) \cong \langle a, b : gaba^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1}, gag^{-1}\rangle$. But the commutator $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $a$ already respect conjugation (I believe) so that the $g$ terms in all the relations become redundant. Then, we are just left with $\mathbb T ^ 2 \vee \mathbb S ^ 2$.
Per @Ben Steffan's helpful suggestion, I replaced my request for a general solution verification with particular areas of concern.
Possible points where my solution could have gone wrong:

Is the fundamental group of $X$ after attaching the three 2-cells truly isomorphic to
$$\langle a, b, c : gaba^{-1}b^{-1}c^3g^{-1}, gag^{-1}, ga^{-1}g\rangle$$
Are we allowed to just forget about $c$ when we take the adjunction space?
How do I justify "breaking up" the fundamental group of $X \cup_{\phi_1} \mathbb D ^ 2  \cup_{\phi_2} \mathbb D ^ 2 \cup_{\phi_3} \mathbb D ^ 2$ into a fundamental group that resembles the torus and what I believe to be a 2-sphere. Is it correct to use Munkres Theorem 68.7 in this context?


What's your question, exactly?

I edited the question saying I'm looking for a solution verification. Thanks

Unfortunately I'll have to quote from the tag description of solution-verification: 'For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.'

Thanks for the advice, I updated my question to highlight the particular points where my solution could have veered off the right course.

Thinking about the fundamental groups is fine, but you're not going to get a homotopy equivalence from this reasoning so easily. I'm not seeing the standard lemmas in Munkres's book, so let me encourage you to look at the result on Hatcher, Chapter 0, Page 13 in my copy (same as PDF numbering). Think carefully about whether the attaching maps in your problem are homotopy equivalent to simpler ones.

@user176372 So, I guess that $\mathbb T ^ 2 \vee \mathbb S ^ 2$ wasn't the correct answer after all? Or, are you saying that I may have guessed the right answer by dumb luck, but my argument to show a homotopy equivalence is not on the right track? This is my first topology course, and our main textbook is Munkres. We have never had a reading formally assigned from Hatcher, although I skimmed sections 1.1 through 1.3. I'll try to read Hatcher Chapter 0. Is that where he mentions the homotopy extension property? Thanks for your comment.

@Talmsmen I'm hesitant to give you an answer one way or the other as this sounds like a homework problem. The result I'm pointing you towards in Hatcher roughly says that if you form a space $Z$ by pasting $X$ into $Y$ along the continuous function $f:A\to Y$ where $A\subseteq X$ is a subspace, then the space $Z'$ obtained by gluing in with a different function $g$ homotopy equivalent to $f$ has $Z\simeq Z'$. Further hint: $\phi_1$ is homotopy equivalent to something simpler once you've pasted in a disc along $\phi_2$ and collapsed the third loop.

Actually, it's a problem from a different year of my course. My final exam is coming up soon, so I thought I could do some last minute studying by reviewing old problems. If you don't feel comfortable giving me a full solution, I completely understand. It's hard to make sure people aren't using this website to cheat. I believe that this question was supposed to be solved by using the cell attachment corollary to Seifart Van Kampen as we haven't covered this result from Hatcher chapter 0. Are you saying that I can neglect the "a" term as well as the "c" term after pasting a disc along $\phi_2$?

I'm sorry if I'm getting hung up on some obvious points. I'm just beginning in topology. I'd like to take another course in the future as I can certainly tell that there are some major holes (no pun intended) in my understanding. Thanks for your assistance.

@Talmsmen Are you 100% sure this question asks for "homotopy equivalence" and not "isomorphic fundamental groups"?

Surprisingly yes, but I'd be happy if I could just find a fundamental group that was isomorphic at the very least.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Now that it has been a week or so, I feel more comfortable coming back to this question with an answer.
Your conclusion is regrettably incorrect, and the overall strategy is reasonably unlikely to lead you to a valid conclusion with proof. At the root, the issue is that spaces which are not homotopy equivalent may have isomorphic fundamental groups. The Siefert-Van Kampen theorem will only yield you algebraic isomorphisms of groups in the best case, not homotopy equivalences of spaces.
This problem is effectively a usual (and bare-bones) way to describe the construction of a particular CW-complex. Hatcher records a standard lemma for this scenario on Page 13 of his textbook. The following is quoted verbatim.

If $(X_1,A)$ is a CW pair and the two attaching maps $f,g:A\to X_0$ are homotopic, then $X_0\sqcup_f X_1 \simeq X_0 \sqcup_g X_1$.

Less formally: Gluing the same space into another along homotopy equivalent paths produces homotopy equivalent spaces. In this case, I recommend building the final space in the following steps.

Collapse c. The resulting space is homeomorphic to the wedge of 2 circles.
Glue in the second and third listed 2-cells. You should be able to convince yourself by a direct argument that the resulting space is the wedge of a sphere with a circle.
Glue in the first listed 2-cell. You should be able to use the above homotopy equivalence result to determine that the map $\tilde\phi_1$ to which the map $\phi_1$ descends in the quotient is homotopy equivalent to a simpler map. So, up to homotopy equivalence, you should be able to observe what the final result is directly.

It looks like the final result is a wedge of two spheres and a circle to me.
